# Principled definition of many particle wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, many-body

In standard texts, I find no systematic and principled definition of a many-particle wave function. Perhaps I am not looking in the right standard textbooks. In my inadequate reading of the literature, I find the same gap. I find various proposed views, some of them slick and quick, but they do not seem to me to be adequately founded in basic principles of quantum mechanics as such, instead coming from apparently personally based or *ad hoc* positions. In standard texts, I find discussions of 'observables' or linear operators that assume that one has at one's disposal priorly defined many-particle wave functions, but, as above, the many-particle wave functions themselves are not actually defined. For me, a wave function must have a straightforward interpretation in terms of the Born rule.

I am primarily interested in the basic reasons and principles, secondarily in the result. Please tell me of a rationally and systematically based and principled definition of a many-particle wave function, strictly based in the founding concepts of quantum mechanics as found in standard text books, or in papers of such authorities as Born, Dirac or Feynman, or whoever you think is in that class.

Comment: References : **(1)** "Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems" by A.L.Fetter & J.D.Walecka, Chapter 1 : Second Quantization
**(2)** "Field Quantization" by W.Greiner & J.Reinhardt, 3. Nonrelativistic Quantum Field Theory.

Comment: In a many body wave function, one has to formulate the potential to enter into the differential equation in order to solve it , for many bodies various quantum mechanical models have been developed that allow modeling the data as for example http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html

Comment: This is nearly in the direction I am looking, which is quantum mechanics as such. I have in mind a wave function for the helium atom. For me, a wave function must have a straightforward interpretation in terms of the Born rule.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first consider a classical $n$-body ensemble of identical bodies. Suppose we have some set of $\mathcal{S}$ of states that one of these bodies can take. Each of these bodies can be in one of these states, so the total state space for the $n$-bodies is $\mathcal{S}^{\times n}$, i.e., the $n$-fold Cartesian power of $\mathcal{S}.$ In other words, every classical $n$-body state can be written as $(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)$ for $s_1,\dots s_n\in\mathcal{S}.$

Now, in quantum mechanics, each one of these distinguishable classical states becomes an orthogonal basis vector of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}.$ In other words, we have a basis vector for each element of $\mathcal{S}^{\times n}.$ The single-body Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_1$ has a basis indexed by $\mathcal{S}.$ There is a mathematical construction that creates $\mathcal{H}$ out of $\mathcal{H}_1$; it is the Tensor product (possibly barring some shenanigans involving infinitely-many bodies). Thus, we have that $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H_1}^{\otimes n}.$

There's another nuance here that I introduced when I stipulated the bodies be identical. Thus, if we exchange any two of the bodies, the state must be indistinguishable from before, i.e., it must pick up a phase. Now, as if we exchange two particles twice we get back the same state, the phase must square to $+1$. Thus, the states must either be completely symmetric or completely antisymmetric (it can get a bit more complicated in some cases; for further reading read up on anyons and fractional statistics).

Comment: For me, a wave function must have a straightforward interpretation in terms of the Born rule.